# Spring Web flow NoSuchConversationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was seeing this exception in the logs intermittently when executing the order flow. Not sure why the system is being thrown

org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController@217e2228]: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException: No flow execution could be found with key '_c733263A4-6F01-E222-AA1D-05475DFE4197_k7F1228F0-709E-EC90-6ABC-DC489BEFD7B5' -- perhaps this executing flow has ended or expired? This could happen if your users are relying on browser history (typically via the back button) that references ended flows.; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.conversation.NoSuchConversationException: No conversation could be found with id '733263A4-6F01-E222-AA1D-05475DFE4197' -- perhaps this conversation has ended?

Does anyone have idea when the spring frame work throws this exception.. How to resolve this ..

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the container session expires.  The following request would create a new session which would not contain the flow and conversation from the previous session.  So when the request processing looks for the flow or conversation it throws that exception.

An easy fix might be to increase the session timeout on your servlet container...